# Factory field isn't being populated if it's already injected into another factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/9n8kdxaz/15/

```
//html
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <h3>
        Select a website
    </h3>

    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option.name for option in apiOptions" ng-change="changeServer(selectedOption)"></select>

        <button type='button' ng-click="submit()">
            Submit
        </button>
        <br>

        <pre ng-show="ready">
            {{data}}
        </pre>
    </div>


</body>


//javascript
angular
    .module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, Config, GetData) {
        $scope.ready = false;
        $scope.apiOptions = [{
            name: "Google",
            baseUrl: "http://google.com"
        }, {
            name: "Amazon",
            baseUrl: "http://amazon.com"
        }, {
            name: "Youtube",
            baseUrl: "http://youtube.com"
        }];

        $scope.changeServer = function(option) {
            Config.setBaseUrl(option.baseUrl);
        }
        $scope.selectedOption = $scope.apiOptions[0];

        if (Config.baseUrl.length <= 1) {
            $scope.changeServer($scope.selectedOption);
        }

        $scope.submit = function() {
            console.log(Config.baseUrl);
            var d = GetData.get();
            d.$promise.then(function(result) {
                $scope.data = result;
                $scope.ready = true;
            })
        }
    })

.factory('Config', function() {
    var config = {};
    config.baseUrl = '';

    config.setBaseUrl = function(url) {
        config.baseUrl = url;
    }

    return config;
})

.factory('GetData', function($resource, Config) {
    return $resource(Config.baseUrl + '/dkajskldas');
})
```

Notice that from the submit() function, I can print Config.baseUrl and it prints as expected. But the GetData factory doesn't have this up-to-date version of Config; in GetData, Config.baseUrl is just the empty initialization string still.

I'm guessing what is happening is that when Config is injected into GetData, it's a new, separate copy of Config.  I was under the impression that factories were singletons and everything would be sharing the same data, though?

I also tried changing Config to a service like so: http://jsfiddle.net/qoygby89/
but still the same problem.

The basic idea was to have the Config factory as a way to share the url between all my various views/controllers/$resource factories.  I could do that with $rootScope instead of a Config factory, but I was trying to avoid that if possible.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is BECAUSE the factory is a singleton. When you inject GetData into the controller, GetData has already been defined as a resource that points to '' + '/dkajskldas' since nothing has been assigned to your Config.baseUrl property at the time the factory ran.

A possible solution would be to have GetData be a function that returns a completely new resource based on the current value of Config.baseUrl

```
.factory('GetData', function($resource, Config) {
    return function() { return $resource(Config.baseUrl + '/dkajskldas'); }
})
```

and then use it in your controller as

```
var d = GetData().get();
```

There's probably a more elegant solution though.

**Edit**: I would probably rename "GetData" to "GetDataResource" for clarity's sake or probably consider creating a service that exposes methods for dynamically creating the resources you need.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense.

Comment: Blah, I hate that I try to hit enter in comments and it submits it.  I always forget.  Anyways, your suggestion does work, so that's a start.  And in the real App, the 'data' factories are things like User, Club, Performer, etc etc.  GetData was just for the example.  But I'm not sure what you mean by that last bit.

Comment: I'm just saying that it might be better practice to name methods as verbs rather than nouns. With this implementation, your resources would be referred to as User(), Club(), Performer(). I would possibly create a ResourceService factory that exposes methods like the answer above for each of your resources so that I can write something like "var d = ResourceService.User().get();" or call it "ResourceService.GetUserResource().get()". Just throwing out stylistic ideas at this point. I'm glad you got it working! :)

Answer (score 0):

Factories are singleton so you are defining the url just in initialization. Try this:

```
.factory('Config', function() {
    var config = {};
    var baseUrl = '';

    config.setBaseUrl = function(url) {
        baseUrl = url;
    }

    config.getBaseUrl = function() {
        return baseUrl;
    }

    return config;
})

.factory('GetData', function($resource, Config) {

    return {
        get: function () {
          var url = Config.getBaseUrl() + '/dkajskldas';
          return $resource(url);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I tried that too, same behavior happens. http://jsfiddle.net/o6vhxvyx/1/